# Restricted Composition

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, integer-partitions

I am trying to find the number of compositions of a given number restricted by the numbers present in a subset.
I read that this is called A-Restricted Composition. where A is a set of numbers

Composition of 10 from set A(1,2,3)

**1**x10

**1**x8+**2**x1

**2**x1+**1**x8

**2**x2+**1**x6

**3**x2+**2**x2

**2**x2+**3**x2 -> Different order than last one

**2**x5

etc etc.

Number of Compositions of a number n = 2^(n-1)

But how can I calculate if the parts of the composition is restricted to a set of numbers, without finding each one of them?

If I try to find each one of them, it could be very erroneous.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) is usually a good first place to look apart from your textbook.  It gives a formula for A-Restricted compositions at the bottom of the page, breaking $n$ into a composition of exactly $k$ terms with each term in $A$ can be done in a number of ways equal to the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $\left(\sum\limits_{a\in A} x^a\right)^k$.  Ranging over all possible $k$ it is then the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of $\sum\limits_{k\in\Bbb N}\left(\sum\limits_{a\in A} x^a\right)^k$

Comment: I did check wikipedia . Looked through the article  qt the bottom. I found the first formula with k restricted summands. But not sure what would be range of k in this. To perform the actual calculation wouldn't I need to know the possible values of k?

Comment: $k$ can be any non-negative integer at all.  Of course, only finitely many $k$ will contribute to the infinite sum in the outerloop so we may stop for example at $k=n$ assuming all elements of $A$ are positive integers.

Comment: Can someone explain what is $x$ in this case?